# Area of shaded region inside rectangle

Tags: geometry

Find the area of shaded region.

[image]

Could someone help me with this? I wrote required area$=2 \times$ Area of semi-circle- Area of rectangle but it gives wrong answer.

Comment: Hint:  by symmetry, the two semi-circular arcs intersect at height $3.5$.  All you need to do is to compute the area of that part of the circle which lies above a chord at that height (and then multiply by $2$).

Comment: **Hint:** Look into the meaning of [sagitta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment) in connection with such areas.

Comment: I know it's not really a clever idea but let's setup an $x$-$y$ coordinate system with the $y$ axis in the middle.

The upper semi-circle has equation 
$$
y = \sqrt{7^2 - x^2}
$$
The intersections of the two semi-circles occur at $y = 7/2$ which gives $x = \pm \frac{7\sqrt{3}}{2}$. Now we lower the semi-circle by $7/2$ to make the intersection point be on the $x$ axes and then compute 
$$
\int_{-\frac{7\sqrt{3}}{2}}^{\frac{7\sqrt{3}}{2}} \sqrt{7^2 - x^2}  - 7/2\ dx
$$ [Result is there](https://tinyurl.com/z26vlo9). Finally you multiply by $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following figur2

[image]

The required area equals the double of the spotted area. The spotted are equals the area of the red circular sector minus the area of the blue edged triangle.

From the equation of the circle centered at the origin, we get that $x=\frac72\sqrt3$. So the opening angle of the red sector is $\pi-2\arcsin\left(\frac{\frac72\sqrt3}{7}\right)=\pi-\frac{\pi}3=\frac{2\pi}3$, that is the red area equals $\frac{49\pi}3.$ 
The area of the triangle is $2x\frac72\frac12=2\frac72\sqrt3\frac72\frac12=49\sqrt3\frac14$.

The result (two times the spotted area):

$$2\cdot 49\left(\frac{\pi}3-\frac{\sqrt3}4\right)=\frac{49}6\left(4\pi-3\sqrt3\right)\approx60.2.
.$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

The shaded region consists of two segments.  Each segments comes from a sector with subtended angle of $120^{\circ}$.

\begin{align*}
  \text{The required area} &=
  2\left(
     \pi \times 7^2 \times \frac{120^{\circ}}{360^{\circ}}-
     \frac{7^2}{2} \sin 120^{\circ}
   \right)
\end{align*}